# Unable to create shortcut on Desktop for a remote IP file

Tags: javascript, windows, wsh

I am using below code to create the help.lnk (which refers to MainHelp.html) from a remote IP to my local system. I am facing below problems:

1. The same code is running on my friends PC but not mine.Its saying = "Automation server can't create object"
2. On my friend's PC the "help.lnk" is targeting to "C:\172.xx.xx.xx\abc\html\MainHelp.html" ,which is wrong as "C:" must not come because the MainHelp.html is present at remote IP.So, its giving Target Not Found ERROR

   function fnGo() 
   {

   ```
   var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell"); 
   strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("\\172.xx.xx.xx\\abc\\html"); 
   var oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "help.lnk"); 
   oShellLink.TargetPath = "\\172.xx.xx.xx\\abc\\html\\MainHelp.html"; 
   oShellLink.WindowStyle = 1; 
   oShellLink.Hotkey = "CTRL+SHIFT+G"; 
   oShellLink.Description = "Shortcut Script"; 
   oShellLink.WorkingDirectory = strDesktop; 
   oShellLink.Save();
   ```

   }

   Please help

Comment: Try target path beginning with triple \ (\\\\)

Comment: @PradyutBhattacharya: Four times \ (\\\\) did the trick :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the following lines

```
strDesktop = WshShell.SpecialFolders("Desktop"); 
var oShellLink = WshShell.CreateShortcut(strDesktop + "\\help.lnk"); 
oShellLink.TargetPath = "\\\\172.xx.xx.xx\\abc\\html\\MainHelp.html";
```

- You need to indicate the correct folder in where to save the shortcut
- It is necessary to separate the name of the shortcut file and the name of the folder
- In javascript, every backslash needs to be escaped, so every backslash needs to be doubled.